# Error: action failed after 10 attempts: failed to connect to the management cluster. Get https://127.0.0.1:43343/api?timeout=30s: EOF

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am creating an `EKS-Anywhere` local cluster by following these steps: [Create local cluster | EKS Anywhere](https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/getting-started/local-environment/)

Getting the following error after executing this command.

`eksctl anywhere create cluster -f $CLUSTER_NAME.yaml`

```
Performing setup and validations
Warning: The docker infrastructure provider is meant for local development and testing only
✅ Docker Provider setup is valid
Creating new bootstrap cluster
Installing cluster-api providers on bootstrap cluster
Provider specific setup
Creating new workload cluster
Installing networking on workload cluster
Installing storage class on workload cluster
Installing cluster-api providers on workload cluster
Moving cluster management from bootstrap to workload cluster
Error: failed to create cluster: error moving CAPI management from source to target: failed moving management cluster: Performing move...
Discovering Cluster API objects
Moving Cluster API objects Clusters=1
Creating objects in the target cluster
Deleting objects from the source cluster
Error: action failed after 10 attempts: failed to connect to the management cluster: action failed after 9 attempts: Get https://127.0.0.1:43343/api?timeout=30s: EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

## Upgrade your `cert-manager`

There is known issue: [clusterctl init fails when existing cert-manager runs 1.0+ · Issue #3836 · kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api/issues/3836)

And there is a solution: [⚠️ Upgrade cert-manager to v1.1.0 by fabriziopandini · Pull Request #4013 · kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api/pull/4013)

And [it works](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api/issues/3836#issuecomment-836599445):

> Cluster API is using cert-manager v1.1.0 now, so this should not be a problem anymore

So, I'd suggest upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a resource constraint on your docker deployment. How much RAM and disk is Docker configured with. I have something like 16gb RAM and 60 gig disk which is more than required, but it does work.

Comment: 8 gb ram + 61 gb free space

Comment: Recommended is 16G of RAM https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/getting-started/install/ You probably don't need 16G, but 8 is not enough